# IQ test question help

Tags: logical-deduction

Can you help me with the solution of the matrix? It has been asked before here [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75711/iq-test-sample-patterns) but a valid and well explained answer was not provided.

[image]

Source without answer: [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75711/iq-test-sample-patterns)

Comment: it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. please provide the source. unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Comment: source: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75711/iq-test-sample-patterns

Comment: @Bee that question focuses on several puzzles including this exact puzzle, but doesnt give an answer to it, also there is reference to the original location so IMO its valid.

Comment: I just feel like the OP of the original question shouldn't have marked it as answered and the solution (if anyone does find one) should definitely be posted and attributed to the original post